# Interpreting KL Divergence Value

Tags: python, scipy

So I am using the scipy library's rel_entr module to calculate KL divergence.
I have read through articles where it is mentioned that a KL divergence output of 0 indicates that the two distributions are essentially the same. Also, I have read that KL divergence is unbounded. So, KL value is between 0 and infinity.

So, given this knowledge, something I have not come across in my research is whether there are 'thresholds' relating to the KL value. What I am saying is, at what value(given by the KL divergence), do I look at the value and conclude that 'P and Q are vastly different'? At what value, do I look at the value and conclude that 'P and Q are vastly similar'?

We know that a value of 0 would mean that p = q but at what value(say 0.5, 0.75 etc) do we conclude that p and q share a majority of 'elements'(using elements here to avoid confusion with values) but differ in some 'elements'?

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question for this forum. However, I think that the value of KL is completely depends on the distribution. Here is a discussion which may help you on this subject: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338016/what-constitutes-a-large-kl-divergence

Comment: this is probably better off as a comment to the question (unlocked after 50 reputation) rather than answer.

Comment: Yes. I can not comment yet:)